# Add custom translation Strings to liferay theme

Tags: java, properties, internationalization, themes, liferay

I want to add some Translations to my Theme to call it with `#language("key")` in my `template.vm` files.
After googling around I have still no clue where to place the `Language.properties` files.

Is it even possible to add Translations to a Theme? If so where I have to place these files?

Thx in advance - Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hook to override the language files.

Refer [Overriding language in below link](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/overriding-a-language-properties-file)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.. Add your "custom-key" on portal-impl.jar file for the language specific properties files. 
You could able to find language properties at portal-impl.jar\content\Language.properties.
On .vm file add #language("custom-key"). 
Restart the server.

Thanks & Regards,
Thiyagu.L

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check this image and hope it is helpful for you
In words create a folder docroot/WEB-INF/src folder this three are not different folder if you see in your project in your package explorer then this is the first folder inside your project.
Thanks and regards
asif aftab

Comment: Just increase the size of web page of browser then image will be visible more clearly.